# Настоящий джангист

Tags: python, django

В связи с поиском работы в области Python/Django возник вопрос: что в Django должен знать каждый соискатель? Конечно, лучше всего фреймворк изучить досконально, но он имеет довольно большой объём и его полное изучение займёт значительное количество времени, а кушать хочется сейчас.

Comment: погуглите что-нибудь вроде "вопросы собеседование django"
Также посмотрите [это][1], [это][2] и [вот это][3]. Возможно, это даст какие-то мысли относительно изучения/повторения/доработки имеющихся навыков. Впрочем, за качество тестов не ручаюсь, поскольку сам никогда их не проходил и Python'ом не занимался вовсе.

[1]:http://www.quizful.net/test/django-python-basics
[2]:http://www.quizful.net/test/python_basics
[3]:http://www.quizful.net/test/python_3_basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Боюсь расстроить, но для хорошей востребованности на рынке труда одним фреймворком не обойдешься.
Что касательно самого фреймворка - не такой уж он и большой как может показаться на первый взгляд, со временем поймешь. Досконально знать и не нужно - важно уметь ориентироваться в документации. Т.е. если сегодня возникла задача сделать какую-то "фишку", то ты должен знать есть ли средства для этого в приделах фреймворка? Если да, то в каком разделе смотреть документацию? Если нет, то идешь искать сторонние пакеты. И только потом, если ничего не найдешь, пишешь свой велосипед ).

Вообще, когда рассматриваешь веб-инструменты как средство заработка, то я бы советовал целиться сразу на конкретную вакансию(в лучшем случае), конкретную компанию или отрасль(на худой конец). Приведу пример двух кардинально отличающихся направления деятельности веб-разработчика:
 1. Поподаешь в крупную команду, которая пилит уже несколько лет социальную сеть, где менеджмент внутри конторы налажен добротно и тебе дают работку по твоему уровню, сидишь там API расширяешь и никуда больше не лезешь.
 2. Маленькая команда которая параллельно штампует мелкие интернет-магазины по несколько штук в месяц. Там тебе нужно будет быть универсальным солдатом: модели, формы, на фронт лезть, платежные системы прикручивать и т.д.
Чувствуется разница? Вот потому конкретного ответа на твой вопрос быть не может.

Comment: Как-бы я уже процентов 30-40 джанговских доков перечитал, бложик-вики написал, в темах, доках, да и вообще в общих чертах представляю себе, как джанго работает, но всегда найдётся 2-3 вотоса, на которых завалят.